# Make a request to API, manipulate the result and make another api request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm here for the first time not to read but to ask a question because I've been losing my mind for two days now on RxJS.

I need to fire two API calls: the first one gets a list of `pricelists`. The response is an object with IDs as keys. I'm leaving a snippet here:

```
{
    "a64cb186455a5a0b5ea1f12e027ce384": {
        "supplier_name": "Supplier_1",
        "pricelists": [
            {
                "status": "enabled",
                "title": "Pricelist_1",
                "pricelist_id": "839b47d67954a9dec375a40652f93b52",
            },
            {
                "status": "expired",
                "title": "Pricelist_2",
                "pricelist_id": "1aed04c948bc63e3b6f8100b0e410afd",

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From this object, I only need the array of pricelists. After that, I also need to filter the pricelists in order to keep only the enabled ones. Then, from the resulting array, I'm checking if there is any pricelist left. If there is at least one pricelist, I save all the pricelists inside an array and I make the first pricelist of the array the selected pricelist.

That said, now I have a selected pricelist. From this point, I need to take the pricelist_id of the selected pricelist, and use it for another api call. The second api call will load the wines inside this pricelist.

I'm leaving a snippet of the response here as well:

```
[
   {
       "producer": "Producer_1",
       "id_prod": "90e2ac8275a68d9eb3a246735e7546cd",
       "wines": [
           {...},
           {...},
           {...},
           {...}
       ]
   },
   {
       "producer": "Producer_2",
       "id_prod": "54e2bf8275a68d9eb3a246735e7546zq",
       "wines": [
           {...},
           {...},
           {...},
           {...}
       ]
   }
]
```

From this array of objects I only need all the objects inside the "wines" keys. So I need to take all of the objects and put them in a single array, so I can for-loop this array on HTML side.

Moreover, there is a modal for changing the selected pricelist. Using the previously saved pricelists, I can change the selected one. When I change the active pricelist, I need to call again the api for loading the wines.

I already implemented all this code but it was a subscribe inside another subscribe, and I don't really like it. It feels hacky and it's not the best way to handle this. I'm leaving the snippet so it's more understandable:

```
  loadPricelists() {
    this.pricelistsService.getConnectionPricelists().subscribe(data => {
      for(let supplier in data) {
        data[supplier]["pricelists"].forEach(pricelist => {
          pricelist["supplier_name"] = data[supplier]["supplier_name"];
          this.pricelists.push(pricelist);
        });
      };  
      this.pricelists = this.pricelists.filter(pricelist => pricelist.status != 'expired');
      if(this.pricelists.length > 0) {
        this.selectedPricelist = this.pricelists[0];
        this.loadPricelistWines(this.selectedPricelist.pricelist_id);
      }
    });
  }

  loadPricelistWines(pricelist_id) {
    this.wines = [];
    this.pricelistsService.getPricelistWines(pricelist_id, this.available_prods).subscribe(data => {
      for(let i in data) {
        this.wines.push(...data[i].wines);
      }
      this.totalWines = this.wines;
      this.selectedPricelist = this.pricelists.filter(prcl => prcl.pricelist_id == pricelist_id)[0];
      this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

So, in syntax, I need to transform the above code in RxJS style
Please help me, I'm really losing my mind!! Any tip will be appreciated!

I tried implement RxJS and I managed to get the pricelists and the wines in the active pricelist, but when I change the active pricelist nothing happens and the HTML is not updated. Also it's not very clear to me what I'm doing with RxJS

Answer (score 1):

Started, got bored...too much in one question.

Here's the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gtdryy?file=index.ts) of where I got to.

Recommend adding types

```
type PriceListStatus = 'enabled' | 'expired';
type PriceList = {
  status: PriceListStatus;
  title: string;
  pricelist_id: string;
};
type SupplierData = {
  supplier_name: string;
  pricelists: Array<PriceList>;
};
type PriceListData = Record<string, SupplierData>;
type WineData = {
  producer: string;
  id_prod: string;
  wines: any[]; // but type this too!
};
```

The key to RxJs is to pipe and only subscribe at the "sink" so there is an unbroken chain from source to sink.

```
const dataToPriceListIds$ = of(PRICE_LIST_DATA).pipe(
  // From this object, I only need the array of pricelists
  // After that, I also need to filter the pricelists in order to keep only the enabled ones
  map((data) => mapToPriceIds(data, 'enabled')),
  debugPipe('Filtered price ids'),
  // Then, from the resulting array, I'm checking if there is any pricelist left.
  filter(isArrayLengthGreaterThanZero),
  debugPipe('Only emit if array greater than zero')
);

const selectedPriceListId$ = dataToPriceListIds$.pipe(
  // first pricelist of the array the selected pricelist
  map((arr) => arr[0]),
  debugPipe('First item of the array')
);

const wineData$ = selectedPriceListId$.pipe(
  // mock api call using id
  switchMap((id) => of(WINE_DATA).pipe(delay(300))),
  debugPipe('Wine data')
);

wineData$.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use [MergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) from RXJS ?

mergeMap allows you to get result from your first API call and set a second API call right after it

something like that :

```
this.service1.Req1()
        .pipe(
            take(1),
            mergeMap(response1 => 
                this.service1.Req2(response1).pipe(
                    take(1),
                    map(response2 => {
                        console.log(response1);
                        console.log(response2);
                    })
                )
            )
        )
```

I'm not really sure I understand your problem, for me what you want to do is a classic api call followed by a second api call depending on the results

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply! Before asking the question here, I tried something similar to your code but with concatMap, and it works when the component loads for the first time. So I guess the first part is correct. The main problem is that the active pricelist can change, and I don't understand how to recall the API (or the observable) again, in order to load the new wines after that change

Comment: Did you try to save the observable in variable ? with that you can call it after more easly ?

Comment: I ended up using two BehaviourSubjects (one for the active pricelist and one for the wines) on the HTML part, so it's always updated, and for the initial part (when you first launch the component) I subscribed to an observable in order to get the data. I don't know if It's the best approach but It's the best way I found yet